# How to implement Heap identify and addUserProperties dynamic for all the members in wix velo corvid

Tags: wix, velo, heap-analytics

How to implement Heap identify and addUserProperties dynamic for all the members in wix velo corvid?

I have implemented the static for both. But in dynamic we have not found any proper solution.

Comment: No idea what you are asking here. Is this about the [Heap analytics platform](https://help.heap.io/getting-started/how-heap-works/what-is-heap/)?

Comment: Yes I am talking about heap analytics platform. We have implemented heap API successfully now the challenge is that to call the heap.identify and heap.adduseeproperties API to make dynamic in Wix velo platform.

Comment: Replaced the [tag:heap] tag with [tag:heap-analytics]. The first has nothing to do with the second.